# Need help changing a value in SQL when searching by a text field

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm writing a program in VB.net to determine the status of a user and using SQL as my db. I have a statement where

```
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE NameOne = '" & nameOneBox.Text & "'" 
    & "AND [LastName] = '" & lastNameBox.Text & "'"
```

finds what I'm looking for exactly but when I do something like this:

```
    @NameOne nvarchar(50), @CurrentStatus bit
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Users
        SET
            CurrentStatus = @CurrentStatus
        WHERE
            NameOne = @NameOne
    END
```

the value CurrentStatus never changes in the database.

Comment: You may need to show more of your code.  I don't see anything wrong with snip of the SP you provided.

Comment: unless you use this partial SP text as your sql text from your VB.NET code. Please add the code where you use the second snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I was mistyping the value for @CurrentStatus and my Try Catch statement wasn't cooperating. If anyone wants me to post the actual code to see what I was doing wrong let me know but other than that, I was really tired and screwed up.